# Google cloud translaet - authentication credential are from different projects

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

Since I've installed the Google cloud console application locally in my computer, I'm getting this error any time my JAVA server make a call to google translate :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-22" com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The API Key and the authentication credential are from different projects.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The API Key and the authentication credential are from different projects.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

    at com.google.cloud.translate.spi.v2.HttpTranslateRpc.translate(HttpTranslateRpc.java:61)
    at com.google.cloud.translate.spi.v2.HttpTranslateRpc.detect(HttpTranslateRpc.java:87)
    at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl$3.call(TranslateImpl.java:79)
    at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl$3.call(TranslateImpl.java:76)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:93)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:49)
    at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl.detect(TranslateImpl.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl.detect(TranslateImpl.java:104)
    at com.exceed.providers.googleapi.GoogleTranslateConnector.detectLanguage(GoogleTranslateConnector.java:49)
    at com.exceed.providers.googleapi.GoogleTranslateConnector.detectLanguageWithConfidence(GoogleTranslateConnector.java:53)
    at com.exceed.services.ConversationManagerService.handleUnknownLanguage(ConversationManagerService.java:369)
    at com.exceed.services.ConversationManagerService.processMessage(ConversationManagerService.java:227)
    at com.exceed.services.FBWebHookService.processMessage(FBWebHookService.java:210)
    at com.exceed.services.FBWebHookService.processMessage(FBWebHookService.java:198)
    at com.exceed.services.FBWebHookService.handleAudio(FBWebHookService.java:181)
    at com.exceed.services.FBWebHookService.processMessageByType(FBWebHookService.java:150)
    at com.exceed.services.FBWebHookService.processRequest(FBWebHookService.java:108)
    at com.exceed.providers.fbmessenger.FBWebHook$1.run(FBWebHook.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've tried looking for some environment variable with Google key, or any other key installed in my computer - but found nothing.

just to be clear, that error rises only in my local computer which i've installed the gcloud console..

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED : 
in my .config directory, there was googleCloudConfig which contains an apiKey, I removed it and everything works well.